# How to cancel event on the bugsnag in C#?

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, bugsnag

How to cancel event on the bugsnag in C#
I try something like the below but its not work

````
    func(event *bugsnag.Event, config *bugsnag.Configuration) error {
        for _, datum := range event.RawData {
            if user, ok := datum.(*MyUserInfo); ok {
                event.User = &User{Id: user.Id}
            }
        }
    }) ```
````

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like the below code:

```
Bugsnag.AspNet.Client.Current.BeforeNotify(report =>
            {
                if (report.Event.Request.Url.Contains("healthcheck.aspx"))
                {
                    report.Ignore();
                }
            });
```